# SnakeYaml not serializing private or protected fields

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I am trying to dump/serialize a Java POJO with SnakeYaml and the private and protected fields are not being serialized.

```
public class Dice {
    private Integer a;
    protected Integer b;
    public Integer c;

    public Dice(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public Integer getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Dice dice = new Dice(1,2,3);
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            String output = yaml.dump(dice);
            System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

which produces the following:

```
!!com.ibm.watson.pml.gpm.plan.Dice {c: 3}
```

I've seen lots of examples that show the private and protected fields being serialized properly.  I've tried 1.17 and 1.23 with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Yaml.setBeanAccess(BeanAccess.FIELD);